# calling modal once text is clicked:Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to show following modal once user click the text. I don't know why it is not working.

```
<span ng-model="nonrelevantData" style="cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: underline;"><b>non-relevant data</b></span>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="bs-example-modal-sm">
<div class="modal-body">
        ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
      ...
</div>                                        
</script>
```

in js

```
$scope.$watch('nonrelevantData', function () {
    $modal({
        template: 'bs-example-modal-sm',
        scope:$scope.$new()
    });
}, true);
```

Comment: Have you looked at angular-ui/ui-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your modal code in a scope function and call that function in ng-click

```
$scope.openModal = function(){
    $modal({
            template: 'bs-example-modal-sm',
            scope:$scope.$new()
        });
}
```

Markup

```
<div ng-click="openModal()">clik me to open</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the plunkr of fancypants (from another question) to make a [Simple Modal Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJf40D9b3pI31QOSKIPu?p=preview)

To listen for clicks you don't need a watcher. The [ngClick directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) can be used for that.